# Is there a difference between port.WriteLine("AT"); and port.Write("AT"+Environment.NewLine);

Tags: c#, at-command

Want to know if there is a difference between the both. Explanation would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WriteLine()

> The default line terminator is a string whose value is a carriage
>   return followed by a line feed ("\r\n" in C#, or vbCrLf in Visual
>   Basic).

Environment.NewLine

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string
>   containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Result the same, but code is different.

```
    protected char[] CoreNewLine = new char[2]
    {
      '\r',
      '\n'
    };    
    public virtual void WriteLine(string value)
        {
          if (value == null)
          {
            this.WriteLine();
          }
          else
          {
            int length1 = value.Length;
            int length2 = this.CoreNewLine.Length;
            char[] chArray = new char[length1 + length2];
            value.CopyTo(0, chArray, 0, length1);
            if (length2 == 2)
            {
              chArray[length1] = this.CoreNewLine[0];
              chArray[length1 + 1] = this.CoreNewLine[1];
            }
            else if (length2 == 1)
              chArray[length1] = this.CoreNewLine[0];
            else
              Buffer.InternalBlockCopy((Array) this.CoreNewLine, 0, (Array) chArray, length1 * 2, length2 * 2);
            this.Write(chArray, 0, length1 + length2);
          }
        }
```